# How to get the year from a string?

Tags: c#, regex

How I can get the year of the following possible strings:

```
"01/01/2003" 
"01/01/03" 
"01-01-03" 
"01-01-2003." 
"Jenuary 01, 2003" 
"Jenuary 01, 03" 
"01 Jen 03" 
"01 jen 2003" 
"Jenuary 01, 2003." 
"Jenuary 01, of 2003."
"01/01/03"
```

How do I get 03 or 2003 
The only rules are:

1. The year is at the end of the string
2. The string may end with "." or space or other character, then ignore it
3. The length of the year may be 2 or 4
4. separators can be "/", "space" and "-"

I can only get the following expression

```
Regex.Match("Jenuary 01, 2003.", @"[^/|^-|^ ]+$").Value
```

but I have the problem that brings me extra characters

```
"Jenuary 01, 2003." I get "2003."
```

thanks in advance

Comment: for extra chars you can you can verify if the length is what you expect 2 or 4

Comment: Are the separators always the same for a single string? Or would 01/01-2003 be valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
\b(?:\d{2}|\d{4})(?=\D*$)
```

Don't know what you mean by #4 since you didn't ask about date format validation, just extracting the last number that's 2 or 4 characters in length from a date string (which the above RegEx does exactly).

Comment: thank you very much, this worked great, is this faster than LINQ?

Comment: Write a test for Linq and Regex methods and use the Stopwatch class to test it out

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need to use a regex for this, this pattern should work for you:

`^.+[-/ ](\d+)\.?$`

Then replace with `\1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to that.According to your rules this should work:

```
var year = input.Split(' ','/','-').Last();
```

More generally:

```
 var dates = new List<string>()
        {
            "01/01/2003",
            "01/01/03",
            "01-01-03",
            "01-01-2003.",
            "Jenuary 01, 2003",
            "Jenuary 01, 03",
            "01 Jen 03",
            "01 jen 2003",
            "Jenuary 01, 2003.",
            "01/01/03"
        };

var years = dates.Select(x => x.Split(' ', '/', '-').Last());
```

Here is the produced result in LINQPad:

[image]

In order to ignore the non-digit characters you can do this:

```
var years = dates
          .Select(x => new string(x.Split(' ', '/', '-').Last()
          .Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray()));
```

Comment: I need the result (year) is not more than numbers (no commas, no points, no spaces, ...)

Comment: @ch2o I updated my answer.it should ignore the dots and other characters.

Comment: @ch2o just `Trim` the resulting string to get rid of dot or add dot into separators list

Answer (score 1):

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(theString);
var year = date.Year;
```

I'm sure there's a better way to account for the culture, but you can do:

```
var adjustedDate = theString.Replace("Jen", "Jan").Replace("jen", "Jan");
var date = DateTime.Parse(adjustedDate);
var year = date.Year;
```

Comment: I'd change it to `DateTime.TryParse()`, but other than that, this is going to be the easiest way by far.

Comment: there are exceptions in some of the strings

Comment: You'll need to use a format provider for your local culture.  Which is that?

Comment: Updated to have a simple solution for the culture.

Comment: I can not use the date function DateTime.TryParse() that can be "rare"

Comment: @ch2o I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: users are creative and may have captured January, jan, Jan, 01, use "of", "th", "rd" (not existed validations dates) and this gives me exceptions in the conversion. Either way I appreciate your help, thnks

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

1. Determine the separator
2. Split the string on the separator
3. Grab the last element (year)
4. Take only the digit characters

This could look something like this:

```
char[] separators = new char[] { '/', '-', ' ' };

//using LINQ
string year = myString.Split(separators).Last().TakeWhile(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToString();
```

Using `.Split` will get you an array of strings, which are the components of the original string as split at the separators. `.Last` will give the you last string.

A string can be treated as an array of `char`s, so we can use `TakeWhile` to take characters from the beginning of the array while a certain condition is true (the `char` is a digit). Since this gives us an array of `char`s, we need to use `ToString()` to make it a string again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the regex:

```
[ -\/](\d{2}|\d{4})[^\d]?$
```

`[ -\/]` means can be space, - or /

`(\d{2}|\d{4})` means 2 or four digits

`[^\d]?` any optional character at the end other than a digit.

`$` is end of the string.

**UPDATE:** If you do not wish to pick group-1 then use this one:

```
(?<=[ -\/])(\d{2}|\d{4})(?=[^\d]?$)
```

Comment: this expression has the problem of having characters at the beginning and end of year 
     "space2005."

Comment: @ch2o Capture group 1 from the `Match m`. Like this one `m.Groups[1].Value`. Or did I misunderstand your comment?

Comment: was using directly .Value without the Groups[]. With string "25-01-2005.space" I get a String.Empty

Comment: @ch2o Please check update, this one is using lookaround and will be slower then other one.

Comment: With update i get string empty with strings "25-01-2005spacespace", "25-01-2005.space "

Comment: @ch2o in your question at point-2 you mentioned `string may end with "." or space or other character` which is singular, means one character. But you are using multiple at the end of string. That's why doesn't work. Your question was confusing. However, just replace the `?` befoer the `$` with a `*`

Comment: Your answer is correct based on the points. but there are every creative person. @tenub response is simpler. anyway I'm grateful with you, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Since all the years are at the end of the string use the Regex option `RightToLeft` to *easily* get at them. To handle the space or period (or any other non digit) use the *ignore any non digit* by using the *not* set of `[^\d]` which says any character *not* a digit.

Then form the pattern for the left to right reading as normal. So we want year digits followed by a non digit to match. Hence is the pattern:

`(\d+)[^\d]?`

Which explained is: the capture group `(\d+)` will consume all numbers followed by a possible non number `[^\d]?`. When run with the `right to left` option the regex parser will unwind our left to right pattern into a right to left and parse the input text in reverse.

See for yourself:

```
var data = new string[]
{
"01/01/2003",
"01/01/03",
"01-01-03",
"01-01-2003.",
"Jenuary 01, 2003",
"Jenuary 01, 03",
"01 Jen 03",
"01 jen 2003",
"Jenuary 01, 2003.",
"Jenuary 01, of 2003.",
"01/01/03",
};


data.Select (dt => Regex.Match(dt, @"(\d+)[^\d]?", RegexOptions.RightToLeft).Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach( year => Console.WriteLine( year ));

/* Output
2003
03
03
2003
2003
03
03
2003
2003
2003
03
*/
```

Comment: @ch2o This answer doesn't need linq, I only use linq to provide the example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do your task with *regular expressions*:

```
    public static int ObtainYear(String value) {
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

      // two ou four digits possibly followed by any spaces and/or dots
      Match match = Regex.Match(value, @"(\d{2}|\d{4})(\.| )*$");

      if (!match.Success) 
        throw new ArgumentException("value");

      int year = int.Parse(match.Groups[0].Value.Trim(' ', '.'), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

      // If you get two digits year you should add either 1900 or 2000
      if (year < 30)
        year += 2000;
      else if (year < 1000)
        year += 1900;

      return year;
    }
    ...

    int result1 = ObtainYear("Jenuary 01, 2003."); // <- 2003 
    int result2 = ObtainYear("01:02:79 ."); // <- 1979
```